# before I've even used the bathroom

Tags: present-perfect

> Woman: It was a mistake.
>
> Man: Since when do you make mistakes?
>
> Woman: What's that supposed to mean?
>
> Man: It means I'm sick of you being so damn perfect all the time.
>   I-I'm sick of the bizarre way your hair doesn't move. I'm sick of you
>   making our bed in the morning **before I've even used the bathroom.**
>   Where's the woman I fell in love with who used to burn the toast and
>   drink milk out of the carton and laugh? I need her

Why did the man use the present perfect? Why not the present simple?

Answer (score 1):

The man could have said, **before I use the bathroom**, but he was talking about something that's in the past, so he probably felt more comfortable with 'used' rather than 'use'.

Another option would have been, **before I used the bathroom**. That feels awkward to me because it doesn't feel like the time period for having used the bathroom is quite as clearly between him having gotten up and her making the bed.

I apologize for not referring to tenses by name, but to me the thought of discussing how to say something by tense feels awkward - like there's only one way to say something in a given tense.  I have a difficult time categorically saying that all ways of saying something in a certain tense versus a different one would be wrong, especially in this case, when I think it could be valid to use simple present, simple past, or present perfect, and it's really just a matter of personal preference.